# Python Type Error: visualize takes exactly 1 argument, 53 given

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, typeerror

I'm using python on my raspberry pi and I keep getting the mentiond Type Error. I have tried many solutions found here and elsewhere, but I cannot make it work. 
My code in the calling method:

```
output_filename_path = "/home/pi/tmp/" + str(output_filename)
print(output_filename_path)
vis_thread = Thread(target = tv.visualize, args=(output_filename_path))
vis_thread.start()
vis_thread.join()
```

I have tried things like os.path.join and ''.join, but none of these worked.

Help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an assumption: You should use

```
args=(output_filename_path, )
```

instead of what you are using. *note the comma* after the variable.

`Thread` needs an iterable, with each element being an argument. Instead you are passing a string (which is an iterable), and python tries to iterate over its characters/